# Does .NET 3.5 SP1 get installed on an XP system if all important windows updates are current?

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-update

I am pretty sure that .NET 3.5 sp1 can be installed on XP through windows update, but I need to know if it is an optional update, or an important update?  I am doing some research to determine what needs to be included in an installer, and this bit of information has been suprisingly hard to find. I don't have an XP VM installed at the moment, or I would just look myself.

Comment: Why is this relevant? You should always include any frameworks necessary with your application when you deploy it. Better yet, let the setup program handle this. Even if it's an "important" update, that's far from a guarantee that users will have it installed.

Comment: @Cody I agree that it needs to be included with the installer (and we do currently install it if it is not installed), but we have certain scenarios where our application may need to be ran on systems where the user does not have admin access (ran on a court room computer for example).  We are just trying to figure out what we could expect from a fully updated machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available on Windows Update but it's optional.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog](http://www.home-server-addins.com/archives/219), .NET 3.5sp1 has been pushed automatically to all supported OSes since 1/27/09.